# Window infinite loop when enable VT-x in bios

Tags: windows-8

Today I tried to enable the `Intel VT-x` in BIOS to work , but after I enabled it, Window was stuck at loading screen.

When I disable the `Intel VT-x` feature, Window is loading normally .

Can anyone tell me the problem here ?

Comment: post more details about your hardware.

Comment: and flavor of Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, When you shut down windows 8/10 it does a [hybrid shutdown](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8/), so when you changed that setting in the bios it locked up when trying to load the OS from the hibernation file.

What you need to do is boot into Windows and hold the shift key down when selecting shutdown, this will force a full shutdown of the OS, then power up and make changes in the bios. This called a cold boot.

If this does not solve it I found one other case [where bluetooth drivers were the cause](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Boot-and-Lockup/Cannot-boot-if-HP-ENVY-Bios-Virtualization-enabled-for-Win8/td-p/2006815/page/5).